# Will an email be sent when a gift card is created via Shopify Gift API?

Tags: shopify

I would like to know if Shopify *will send an email to the Customer I associate with*, when I create a Gift Card using Shopify's [Gift Card API](https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/gift_card#create)?

A customer can be associated to a Gift Card via its properties.

```
"customer_id": 1234
The id of a customer who is associated with this gift card.
```

Refer Gift Card properties section in [this](https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/gift_card) page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Shopify will send email and SMS to the customer regardless if it is created through admin or API

Comment: Thank you. I couldn't find this information from Shopify's site. Would you mind sharing the URL where you found this information?

Comment: I've just tested on my Shopify Plus account